# Pass multiple directories to find in Mac for removing .DS_Store files

Tags: find, cron

I have a defined list of directories that contain development code that I want to make sure that any `.DS_Store` files are never present, or removed shortly after being created.

I will do this via `crontab` but I would like to pass all the said directories at once if possible, as opposed to running multiple `crontab` functions.

In my `crontab`:

```bsh
15 * * * * root find /Users/vince/directories -name “.DS_Store” -depth -exec rm {} \;
```

In `directories` above I want to pass `Code`, `Sites` and a couple others.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Side note: you don't want these fancy quote characters `“...”`. If anything, you want plain ASCII quote characters `"..."` or `'...'`.

Comment: "In `directories` above I want to pass `Code`, `Sites` and a couple others." -- What do you mean? You can specify multiple directories as arguments to `find`: `find /foo /bar/baz /another ...`. Or is `directories` a regular file where you want to specify paths as strings? If so then `find /Users/vince/directories ...` is misleading. Please [edit] and clarify. Usually a solution to "as opposed to running multiple `crontab` functions" is to write a script that runs multiple commands and can be invoked from a single crontab line.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the word `root` in your `crontab`? If you need privilege elevation to get this job done you should run it in the `root crontab` using `sudo crontab -e`.

Comment: @Seamus System-wide crontab (e.g. `/etc/crontab`) has the username field, at least in Debian and derivatives. Conceptually root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`) is still a user's crontab, it's just the user happens to be root. I would use it for tasks root wants to do for himself, just like any other user's crontab is basically for things the user wants to do for himself. In this model the system-wide crontab files are the right place for administrative tasks.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Fair point, but the OP said `my crontab`, not `/etc/crontb`, so...?

Comment: @Seamus Yes, it may be the OP uses the wrong syntax; or just unfortunate wording (e.g. I am the only user of my laptop and I consider all files in `/etc` or anywhere to be "mine"). Hopefully in this aspect Vince knows what he's doing. If not, our comments will give him some hints. I admit I don't know Mac and its implementation of cron, but I suspect the user's crontab has no username field (the field wouldn't make sense, I guess). So Vince, if you really mean *your* personal crontab then verify if the word `root` fits there. Seamus's concern makes sense.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: re Mac: Good point - Apple has rather *buggered* `cron`. It's still installed, and operational last I used it, but requires `cron` be given "Full Disk Access" in the Privacy tab. And, AFAIK there is no `/etc/crontab` - not on my system anyway.  Yeah - it's messy.

Answer (score 1):

- The personal crontab of a user should not have a username its 6th field (yours have `root` there).  If you want the root user to run the job, then add the job to root's crontab using `sudo crontab -e`.
- The `find` utility takes a list of top-level search paths:

  ```bsh
  find /some/path/a /some/path/b /other/path ...expression...
  ```
- Use straight quotes (`"..."`) in the shell, not fancy or typographical quotes (`“...”`).  The string that you are quoting, `.DS_Store`, does not need quoting.
- The `find` utility on macOS has `-delete`, which implies `-depth`.
- The home directory of a particular user, `vince`, can portably be referred to using `~vince`.

Taking the above points into account, you may end up with a schedule looking something like this:

```
15 * * * * find ~vince/Code ~vince/Sites ~vince/"other dir" -type f -name .DS_Store -delete
```